# How to replace character values inside the first two digits

Tags: r, regex

```
string1 <- c("4 ft. x 6 ft. Area")
string2 <- c("text text 12 ft. x text text 12 ft. X 20 ft. text text")
```

I want to remove all the text, meta-characters within the first two digits. Desired output is shown below:

```
output1 <- 46
output2 <- 1212
```

I tried using `gsub("\\d.+?\\d","",string1)` which gives output as `" ft. Area"`. What should I do?

Comment: You could use `(\d+)\D*(\d+)` and concenate group 1 and 2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. It not only worked but also empowered me with the logic to solve such problems. Yesterday i tried many times to upvote but couldn't because of less rep. Today, it should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```
s <- c("4 ft. x 6 ft. Area", "text text 12 ft. x text text 12 ft. X 20 ft. text text")
sub("\\D*(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", s)
## => [1] "46"   "1212"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/CODCiM)

**Details**:

- `\\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `(\\d+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern)
- `\\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `(\\d+)` - Group 2 (referred to with `\2`) capturing 1+ digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of string.